SSH Hostname not being binded to IP from one windows device. Works from another
Setting up a network fleet for long distance work from educational institution laptop device and personal device, connection through SSH on my Ubuntu Server. I use CMD in Win 10/11 on my two client devices.
Device 1: ssh username@hostname

connects to 192.168.1.xxx

Device 2: ssh username@hostname

could not resolve hostname 'hostname': no such host is known

Device 2 try 2: ssh username@ip

resolves to ip address

I'm trying to troubleshoot and identify what's causing this. It's not network, it's not hostname addressing.
My only guess is something to do with DHCP addressing which I don't have the first clue as to where to begin.
The project plan was to setup DDNS binding to host/mac addressing while using a VPN + Authentication for my security. Port forwarding to internal IPs for the encapsulation.
I'm starting with baby steps, and getting my LAN setup first.
I'm using Dynamic addressing -> therefore I don't want to memorize the IPs -> Prefer hostnames
Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

To test my theory: on device 2 run nslookup hostname and ping hostname. And if they fail, then it means the hostname isn’t being resolved.
